# Python async client-to-client and server-to-server proxy

Tags: python, python-asyncio

As an input - exist one device which only is able to connect to 2 remote ports and redirect data through this connections.
I try to write a 2 specific proxy servers. One which will work on this device, and other one which will listen to two ports on the localhost and forward data through it.

I wrote this code, but it do not work for some reason.
When I try to open https://127.0.0.1:4000 server-to-server proxy got the data, but client-to-client shows no data and I can not see the web server running on the address 192.168.0.5.
Can you please help me, what is the problem?

client-to-client proxy

```
import asyncio

async def forward_data(source_reader, destination_writer):
    while True:
        data = await source_reader.read()
        if not data:
            break
        destination_writer.write(data)
        await destination_writer.drain()
    destination_writer.close()

async def run_server():
    reader1, writer1 = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 5000)
    reader2, writer2 = await asyncio.open_connection('192.168.0.5', 443)
    await asyncio.gather(
        forward_data(reader1, writer2),
        forward_data(reader2, writer1)
    )

asyncio.run(run_server())
```

server-to-server proxy

```
import asyncio

async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    while True:
        try:
            data = await reader.read()
            if not data:
                break
            writer.write(data)
            await writer.drain()
        except ConnectionResetError as e:
            print(f"Connection reset by peer: {e}")
            break

    writer.close()

async def start_server():
    server_4000 = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, '127.0.0.1', 4000)
    server_5000 = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, '127.0.0.1', 5000)
    await asyncio.gather(server_4000.serve_forever(), server_5000.serve_forever())

asyncio.run(start_server())
```

Comment: which bit does not work ?  what is the error ?  where are you stuck ?

Comment: @D.L done. I have no errors, but the client-to-client proxy does not receive any data for some reason which I don't understand.